# How to maximise a function with non-differentiable constraints while integrating over a time series data series with linear programming?

Tags: linear-programming, python, pyomo

In this problem, I need to pick the optimal charging and discharging times and durations of an electric car-sharing battery to maximize income - not just for a single (dis)charging cycle, but a whole bunch, with some car-sharing bookings that must work in between.

The curve in the graph is the time series data of the energy price $P(t)$. The red box is a car-sharing booking, which pauses the (dis)charging. It discharges the battery by $\Delta \text{SoC}_{b_n}$. Left of the booking is a discharging period starting at $I_n$, lasting for $\Delta i_n$. On the right is a charging time at $S_n$ for the duration of $\Delta s_n$.

The red line signifies the state of the battery charge (state of charge, SoC), which follows the charging and discharging cycle and the usage of the car.

[image: sketch of the price data and the naming of my variables]

My objective function is

$$
f_{objective} = \sum_{n=0}^{m} \int\limits_{I_n}^{I_n + \Delta i_n} P(t) \,dt - \int\limits_{S_n}^{S_n + \Delta s_n} P(t) \,dt 
$$

Here, I directly integrate the price data $P(t)$ with my variables, setting the intervals and the times.

The constraints are primarily for SoC: At no time can the battery be fuller than 100% and emptier than 0%. I try to express that with the upper bound of the sum of $1 .. m$.  ($c$ is the charge/time factor)

$$
0  \leq \sum_{n=0}^{1..m} -\Delta i_n \cdot c - \Delta \text{SoC}_{b_n} + \Delta s_n \cdot c \leq 1
$$

and even the individual charges can never leave the SoC-interval of 0..1:

$$
0  \leq \Delta i_n \cdot c \leq 1, \quad
0  \leq \Delta \text{SoC}_{b_n}  \leq 1, \quad 
0  \leq  \Delta s_n \cdot c \leq 1
$$
The (dis)charging and booking times can not overlap.
$$
I_n + \Delta i_n < B_n, \quad 
B_n + \Delta b_n < S_n, \quad 
S_n + \Delta s_n < I_{n+1}   
$$

I wrote some python code for this and ran into problems with the integration. I have difficulty understanding the pyomo `Integral` function and how to use it, especially with my time series data. I tried to integrate with NumPy functionality, but that fails. Can you please help me make this work? I am a pyomo noob and still struggle with concepts and terminology.

```
import numpy as np
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory

def make_demo_data():
    x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
    y = np.sin(x) + 1.5 -x*.025  # add offset to make sure all values are positive
    return np.array([x, y])

def integrate(data_a, x, delta_x):
    x = x.values
    delta_x = delta_x.values
    scaling_factor = 100 / (4*np.pi)
    x_start = x
    x_end = x + delta_x
    x_data = np.linspace(x_start, x_end, 5)
    y_interp = np.interp(x_data, data_a[0], data_a[1])
    earning = np.trapz(y_interp, x_data * scaling_factor)
    return earning

data = make_demo_data()

model = ConcreteModel(name="(DischargePlan)")

# define variables
model.i = Var(domain=NonNegativeReals, name="i")
model.delta_i = Var(domain=NonNegativeReals, name="delta_i")
model.s = Var(domain=NonNegativeReals, name="s")
model.delta_s = Var(domain=NonNegativeReals, name="delta_s")

model.objectives = Objective(expr=integrate(data, model.i, model.delta_i) - integrate(data, model.s, model.delta_s), sense=maximize)

model.constraints = ConstraintList()
model.constraints.add(model.i + model.delta_i <= np.pi)
model.constraints.add(model.s + model.delta_s <= 2*np.pi)
model.constraints.add(1 - model.delta_i + model.delta_s <= 1)
model.constraints.add(1 - model.delta_i  <= 1)
model.constraints.add(1 - model.delta_i + model.delta_s > 0)
model.constraints.add(1 - model.delta_i > 0)

solver = SolverFactory('CPLEX')
solver.solve(model)
print(model.objectives())
print(f"i = {model.i.values}, delta_i = {model.delta_i.values}, s = {model.s.values}, delta_s = {model.delta_s.values}")
```

Comment: In the integrate func, you use values for $\delta_i$. $ \delta_i$ is your variable to be used in the obj. Does Pyomo allow to use $ \delta_i$.values() before solving?

Comment: @Sutanu I don't know. The problem requires $\Delta i$ and $\Delta s$ to be used in some shape or form. Can you suggest a workaround?

Comment: try writing the objective function without using delta_i instead of delta_i .values. Also I think, obj needs to be an expression, not returning value of a function, like obj = <<expr>>. Then in the Objective(expr=obj,..)

Comment: @Sutanu is it ok to use $I_n$ and $S_n$ in the objective function?

Comment: Yes but again need to double check if you should use x or x.values

Comment: try this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1116267/how-do-i-optimize-a-function-with-an-integral-in-it. You need to use the derivative of the integral function, basically the func and solve it. Repeat for the values within integral bounds.

Comment: @Sutanu , I read and re-read the answer you mentioned. Still, even if I used the differentiated data when inserting the limits like in the example, you end up with $\Delta i$ and $\Delta s$ in the objective function. Still, this seems to offer a precise continuous solution, which others tell me my problem can't have. And continuous instead of discrete is what i would prefer.

Comment: How do you model the car-sharing booking aka the red box? Do you assume that $S_n - B_n$ alway equals a time interval of one hour? In addition, you didn't mention how the SoC exactly changes during the booking (aka the red box). That said, that's a typical mixed-integer optimal control problem. You want to minimize some functional subject to some integer-valued constraints.

Comment: @joni, nice to see you. I followed your recommendation. :-) I model the booking as just one timeslot with a defined discharge amount. with my current model, I have just one variable (soc) per timeslot and several constraints depending on the boundary conditions. The timeslots are currently just one minute long, which gives me several thousand variables. I would like a non-discrete model with actual integration over the price, but I wasn't able to figure that out yet.

Comment: I see. Another question: Could you elaborate on your notation regarding the indices? Each of your time points $I_n, B_n, S_n$ is indexed by $n$ and you sum up the objective from $n = 0, \ldots, m$. I assume that $n$ is the index of the $n$-th time point of your (discretised) time horizon and $m$ is the index of the last time point in your (discretised) time horizon?

Comment: @joni Your assumptions are correct. Note that any of the $I_n$, $B_n$, or $S_n$ could be zero, so all combinations can be represented. Do you think it would help to paste my discrete solution here, so someone might suggest a continuous one?

Comment: @AndreasSchuldei Sure. I'll probably post an answer for the continuous case tomorrow or at the weekend.

Answer (score 1):

This is an attempt at a solution. It has several shortcomings.

- it is a discrete solution
- it does not have bookings yet
- it should handle different buying and selling prices, but it does not.

On the upside

- it does buy and sell
- it handles a few thousand variables nicely

Some of this is most likely a z3 limitation. I will try with another optimizer next.

```
import numpy as np
from z3 import *

CHARGING_CONST = 1/3
START_VAL = 1.0
NUM = 20

def make_demo_data():
    x = np.linspace(0, (4 * np.pi), NUM)
    y = np.sin(x) +1.5 -.025 * x
    z = np.sin(x) * 3 -.027 * x
    data = np.zeros(NUM, dtype=([("time", float), ("price", float), ("price_co2", float)]))
    data["time"] = x
    data["price"] = y
    data["price_co2"] = z
    return data

data = make_demo_data()
soc = []

o = z3.Optimize()
soc.append(z3.Real("soc_0"))
o.add(soc[0] <= START_VAL + CHARGING_CONST)
o.add(soc[0] >= START_VAL - CHARGING_CONST)
o.add(soc[0] >= 0)
o.add(soc[0] <= 1)
f_obj = 0
f_obj += data["price"][0] * (START_VAL - soc[0])

for cnt in range(1, NUM):
    soc.append(z3.Real(f"soc_{cnt}"))
    o.add(soc[cnt] <= soc[cnt - 1] + CHARGING_CONST)
    o.add(soc[cnt] >= soc[cnt - 1] - CHARGING_CONST)
    o.add(soc[cnt] >= 0)
    o.add(soc[cnt] <= 1)
    f_obj += (soc[cnt - 1] - soc[cnt]) *\
        z3.If(soc[cnt - 1] >= soc[cnt],
           data["price"][cnt],
           data["price_co2"][cnt])
# data["price"][cnt]

o.add(soc[-1] == START_VAL)
o.maximize(f_obj)
print(o.check())
m=o.model()

for cnt in range(NUM):
    print(f"""{cnt}: {m.evaluate(soc[cnt]).as_decimal(2)}""")

print(f"Result: {m.evaluate(f_obj).as_decimal(2).strip('?')}")
```