# How to change the price in the objective function, depending on its sign, in python, with Z3?

Tags: python

My objective function is

$$
f_{objective} = \sum_{n=0}^{m} \int\limits_{I_n}^{I_n + \Delta i_n} P_{normal}(t) \,dt - \int\limits_{S_n}^{S_n + \Delta s_n} P_{CO_2}(t) \,dt 
$$

($P(t)$ is the price,) and it boils down to this in python:

```
        ...

        obj_func += self.price(soc[i - 1] - soc[i], i)

        ...

def price(self, delta_soc, index):
    if delta_soc >= 0:
        return delta_soc * self.data["price_co2"][index]
    else:
        return delta_soc * self.data["price"][index]
```

except it does not work like that. I get the error message.

```
z3.z3types.Z3Exception: Symbolic expressions cannot be cast to concrete Boolean values.
```

and I understand why that is. But how can I work around that? Is there a trick so I can sell at another price than when I buy?

Comment: Z3 (and z3py) has an If function. See the documentation. Not at all obvious that Z3 is a good tool for this problem.

Comment: @erwin-kalvelagen, what is a proper tool for this problem? It must be fast because I must run this frequently with ~1440 variables.

Comment: Of course, it depends on many things (characteristics of the model, nonlinearities, amount of money available to buy solvers, academic/commercial etc.).  1440 variables is usually small these days.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen I am in the academic context, but I prefer free software solutions. I am working on this https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/9853/how-to-maximise-a-function-with-non-differentiable-constraints-while-integrating, which is non-linear. I hear open-source solvers are not close to commercial ones. But could Pulp be good enough?

Comment: That is not a very well-researched question: (1) PuLP is not a solver and (2) PuLP only supports linear models. I would suggest to do a little bit of a literature search, and see what colleagues did.  That can help with the modeling part and give an idea about the kind of solvers used for your type of model.

Comment: You are right. This is outside my core competence and I just want to solve the problem at hand. :-)

Answer (score 3):

It took me a while to get the syntax right, so I share it for later generations. This seems to work as intended:

```
        obj_func += (soc[i - 1] - soc[i]) * \
                    z3.If(soc[i - 1] >= soc[i],
                          self.data["price"][i],
                          self.data["price_co2"][i])
```

Comment: While this should work in principle, it is not useable in z3. Z3 becomes super slow and does not terminate.